# Google API pie chart with lines

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api

Does anyone know or it's possible to get the labels outside the Google API pie chart and not IN it? I know it's possible with the image version:
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&cht=p3&chl=Hello|World

But I like to get it work with this version (with the lines like the previous link, would be nice):
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Comment: I don't see anything in the configuration options that enables this https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options

Comment: Well... I think I found it: 'labeled' - Draws lines connecting slices to their data values. See legend.position at https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: 'labeled' - Draws lines connecting slices to their data values. See legend.position at https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options